# Given 6 pairs of twins, how many ways to chose 3 groups of 4 with no twins in the same group?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A class contains 12 students in 6 pairs of twins. In how many ways can we pick 3 groups of 4 students, without any of them containing a pair of twins?

I solved this problem for 2 groups of 6 easily with the multiplication principle. Every group must contain one person from each pair, so we get $2^6$ different groups.

Any hints on how to solve it for 3 groups of 4?

Comment: Are you sure that your answer to splitting the $12$ people into $2$ groups is correct? Try the case with $2$ pairs of twins - i.e $4$ people overall. Are there $2^2$ ways to split the $2$ pairs of twins into $2$ groups (as your 'multiplication' method would suggest)?

Comment: You're right! I guess i forgot to divide by 2 at the end, so the correct solution was $2^5$, and for n pairs $2^n$, correct?

Comment: @ManoPlizzi:  that is right.  It is the equivalent of the divide by $6$ in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each group must share two pairs with each other group.  For the first group we can select the four pairs in ${6\choose 4}=15$ ways and select the individuals in $2^4=16$ ways. Then for the second group we choose two of the four of the first group to get the mates of, ${4 \choose 2}=6$ ways and choose which of the other two pairs to pick $2^2=4$ ways.  But we could have formed the groups in any of $3!=6$ orders and gotten the same groups.  This gives overall $\frac {15 \cdot 16 \cdot 6 \cdot 4}{6}=960$ ways.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that each group must share two pairs with each other group?  (I certainly believe it, but I wasn't sure how to show it.)

Comment: @user84413: If any two groups share more than two pairs, they can't take at least one from each pair and the third group will be stuck with two from the same pair.  But each pair must be shared between two groups, so any two groups must share exactly two pairs.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me, and for the nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Just another way:**

If we pretend to divide into two groups,
the last two of the first and first two of the second (put in parentheses) must be different, e.g.

$ABCD(EF)(BD)\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\;$ and chosen in $\binom62\binom42 = 90$ ways

But we are actually forming three groups,
and taking the groups to be unlabelled and the twins to be non-identical ones, $$\text{we get}\;\; \frac {90\cdot2^6}{3!} = 960\;\;\text{ways}$$